# How to zip one column of a dataframe (x) with each n columns of another (x1, x2, x3, x4, xn) and calculate lev distance for each pair?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, levenshtein-distance, python-zip

I have a df containing names and urls

```
data = [
    ['name1', ''],
    ['name2', 'name2.com'],
    ['name3', 'name3.com, name4.com, name5.com' ],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["name", "url"])
```

I need to calculate the levenshtein distance between each name and each url, the url column sometimes has multiple urls separated by a comma (but not a list) and I don't know if and how many are concatenated in advance. Sometimes that column is blank.

The actual list I am working with has thousands of rows

```
from Levenshtein import distance as lev
```

I tried creating a separate df exploding the 'url' column and splitting it by the comma:

```
df1 = df['url']
df1 = df1.str.split(',', expand=True)
```

I don't know how to make it check each column in df1 against the name in df, so I hard coded the variables and added the columns if no columns were exploded

```
# add columns if they don't exist
df1 = df1[0].to_list()
cols = [0,1,2]
df1 = df1.reindex(df1.columns.union(cols, sort=None), axis=1, fill_value='')


# create variables for each item to compare

name = df['name']

url0 = df1[0]
url1 = df1[1]
url2 = df1[2]

# create list for each calculation

url0_vs_name = []
url11_vs_name = []
url2_vs_name = []


#calculate Levenshtein distance between names and urls

for a, b in zip(name, url0):
    url0_vs_name.append(lev(a, b))
    
for c, d in zip(name, url1):
    url1_vs_name.append(lev(c , d))
    
for e, f in zip(name, url2):
    url2_vs_name.append(lev(e , f))
        
# append results to dataframe
col_list = ['url0_vs_name']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(url0_vs_name, columns=col_list)
df1['url1_vs_name'] = pd.DataFrame(url1_vs_name)
df1['url2_vs_name'] = pd.DataFrame(url2_vs_name)
```

This works but I may have 10 columns in df1 or just 1. Is it possible to calculate each name vs each url and append the result without specifying all df1 columns?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

1. First, the rows with an empty url are removed, because I suppose they are of no interest when calculating the levenshtein disance. I achieve the removal with the methods replace and dropna ("inplace = True" is to update the changes on the same df and not create a different object)

```
df.replace("", np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace = True)
```

2. Then, I use the aaply method, that performs a function on every element of a pandas Series (in this case, the url column). This function is explicitely defined using lambda. Now that the cells have been transformed to lists, the column can be exploded and now you have a df where the distance can be compared row by row between each element of the column

```
df['url'] = df['url'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', '))
df.explode('url')
```

This is the result:

```
    name        url
1  name2  name2.com
2  name3  name3.com
2  name3  name4.com
2  name3  name5.com
```